# How to unflatten Observable<List<T>> into Observable<Observable<T>>

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have an `io.reactivex.Observable` that emits lists of elements of type `T` which can be distinguished by an identifier (key). `Observable<List<T>>`

Each emission `List<T>` can:

- introduce new elements (emitted list contains element with new identifier)
- update existing elements (emitted list contains element with same identifier as element from previous emission)
- remove obsolete elements (emitted list does not contain element with specific identifier anymore)

Now I need to setup a reactive pipe for each element that processes all its updates and eventually completes once no more update is emitted. Therefore I want to `Observable.flatMap()` each emitted list into an observable of observables of elements. `Observable<Observable<T>>`

> **Practical example:** Let's say I have a hot observable that emits a list
> of weather alerts. An alert can be updated with new values during
> subsequent emissions. New alerts can be emitted at any time (together
> with all other current alerts). Now I have to process each alert over
> its whole life cycle separately. For each alert I need a dedicated
> observable which emits the initial value and all updates and finally
> completes. And for each alert I will dynamically create a dedicated
> consumer.
>
> **the fist emission might look like this:** `[Alert1, Alert2]` -> after the
> transformation I expect two emissions: The first is an observable
> which itself emits `Alert1` and the second is another observable which
> itself emits `Alert2`.
>
> **second emission:** `[Alert1, Alert2, Alert3]` -> after the transformation I
> expect one new emission: An observable which itself emits `Alert3`.
> Apart from that the two observables emitted in the first step each
> would emit a new event `Alert1` respectively `Alert2`.
>
> **third emission:** `[Alert2, Alert3]` -> after the transformation I expect
> no new emission. But the first emitted observable from step 1 would
> now complete because `Alert1` is not in the list anymore. The other
> observable from step 1 and the observable from step 2 would each emit
> `Alert2` respectively `Alert3`.

The transformation function takes as parameter a keySelector function or any onther means to determine whether two elements have the same identifier. It should emit an observable for each new element it encounters which in turn should emit the the initial state and all updates of that element.

The whole thing is similar to groupBy operator, but differs in that it takes a list of elements as input and the returned Observable completes as soon as a list is received that doesn't contain the element anymore.

I wrote an exemplary implementation of the transformation function but it seems inefficient, bulky, and overly complex. Does anyone have a cleaner approach to this problem?

```
class GroupMapper<T, K> implements Function<List<T>, Observable<Observable<T>>> {
    
    private final Function<T, K> keySelector;
    private final HashMap<K, Observer<T>> groupsMap;

    public GroupMapper(Function<T, K> keySelector) {
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
        this.groupsMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Observable<T>> apply(List<T> list) {
        List<T> newElements = new LinkedList<>();
        List<T> updatedElements = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Observer<T>> removedElements = new LinkedList<>();

        list.forEach(el -> {
            if (groupsMap.containsKey(keySelector.apply(el))) {
                updatedElements.add(el);
            } else {
                newElements.add(el);
            }
        });

        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<K, Observer<T>>> it = groupsMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

            Map.Entry<K, Observer<T>> entry = it.next();
            if (list.stream().map(keySelector).noneMatch(entry.getKey()::equals)) {
                removedElements.add(entry.getValue());
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        // dispose removed elements
        removedElements.forEach(Observer::onComplete);

        // update existing elements
        updatedElements.forEach(el -> groupsMap.get(keySelector.apply(el)).onNext(el));

        // add new elements
        return Observable.fromIterable(newElements).map(el -> {
            Subject<T> sub = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(el);
            groupsMap.put(keySelector.apply(el), sub);
            return sub;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow.  In the first place, if you are using `Stream.flatMap()`, then you must map each element of the input stream to a *`Stream`* of elements of the output map.

Comment: In the second place, it doesn't make sense to emit `Observable<Observable<T>>` at all.  Presumably, the consumers of per-item notifications will instead want just `Observable<T>`, so possibly you want a stream of those.

Comment: In the third place, you seem to be missing a key component: something that receives notifications on the original `Observable` and de-multiplexes them into appropriate `notifications` on the per-item `Observable`s.  Since your `GroupMapper` holds the map of individual `Observable`s, privately, it's the only object in position to do that, but it does not appear actually to do so.

Comment: Overall, I don't see why you are trying to implement this as a stream operation at all.  The mapping that it seems to me needs to be performed is from groupwise observations to per-item observations, and the groupwise observations do not arrive in stream form -- they arrive via callback invocations.

Comment: You can use the `scan` operator to combine each list emitted by your observable with with the previous emission.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry for the confusion. I don't want to Stream.flatMap() I want to Observable<List<T>>.flatMap().

Comment: In that case, @KlausSchumacher, it would be in order to specify *which `Observable`* you are using.  The Java standard library has two (one a class, the other an interface), and neither has a `flatMap()` method.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I am using RxJava, hence io.reactivex.Observable. I guess the rx-java tag I attached to this question wasn't quite enough. I added this piece of information to the description above. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnWowUs, using the scan operator I might get rid of the HashMap but I would still need to identify which elements were updated, which are new and which are obsolete. Do you know of an elegant way to achieve that?